# React: change from class based components to functional based components

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

This is a react beginners exercise so I'm looking for the simplest solution. I need to **convert these 3 class components into functional components.** I'm currently learning React so any helpful comments would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**APP.JS**

```
import React from 'react'
import List from './components/List'


class DataArr extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const fruits = ["banana", "apple", "pear", "melon", "lemon"]

    return (
    <div className="DataArr">
      <List fruits={fruits}/>
    </div>
    )
}
}

export default DataArr;
```

**LIST.JS**

```
import React from "react";

import Item from "./Item"; 

class List extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
          return <Item key={index} fruit={fruit} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default List;
```

**ITEM.JS**

```
import React from 'react'
class Item extends React.Component{
    render() {

        return (
              <div>
                {this.props.fruit}
              </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default Item;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a step by step answer on How to Convert React Class Component to Functional Component which is nicer, cleaner and easier to read:

1. You need to change the class to a function
2. Remove `render` function
3. Remove `this` keyword
4. If you have `state` in your `Class Component` use `hooks` and in particular `useState` or `useReducer` hook
5. If you used `lifecycle methods` in your `Class Component` you can almost use `useEffect` hook in every situation. (just need to be comfortable with it which you can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/))

`App.js` would be:

```
import React from 'react'
import List from './components/List'


// class DataArr extends React.Component { //<-- Remove this line
const DataArr = () => { // <-- Create a function Component
  // render() { // <-- remove render function because you don't need it
    const fruits = ["banana", "apple", "pear", "melon", "lemon"]
    return (
      <div className="DataArr">
        <List fruits={fruits}/>
      </div>
    )
// } // this curly brace is for render function
}

export default DataArr;
```

`List.js` would be:

```
import React from "react";

import Item from "./Item"; 

// class List extends React.Component { //<-- Remove this line

const List = (props) => {
// render() { // <-- remove render function because you don't need it
    return (
      <div>
        {
          // this.props.fruits.map((fruit, index) => { <-- Change this.props to props
          props.fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
          return <Item key={index} fruit={fruit} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  // } // this curly brace is for render function
}
export default List;
```

and the `ITEM.js` would be like this:

```
import React from 'react'
// class Item extends React.Component{ //<-- Remove this line
const Item = (props) => { // <-- Create a function Component
  // render() { // <-- remove render function because you don't need it
    return (
          <div>
            {
              // this.props.fruit // <-- change this.props to props
              props.fruit
            }
          </div>
    )
}
// } // this curly brace is for render function
export default Item;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular instance, conversion is straight forward as they are simple 'dumb' components. You just remove the classes, convert them into standard functions with their props passed as a parameter, remove the `render()` and replace with a `return`.

APP.JS

```
import React from 'react'
import List from './components/List'

function DataArr() {
    const fruits = ["banana", "apple", "pear", "melon", "lemon"];

    return (
        <div className="DataArr">
          <List fruits={fruits}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DataArr;
```

LIST.JS

```
import React from "react";

import Item from "./Item"; 

function List({ fruits }) {
    return (
      <div>
        {fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
          return <Item key={index} fruit={fruit} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
}

export default List;
```

ITEM.JS

```
import React from 'react';

function Item({ fruit }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {fruit}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

**APP.JS**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import List from './components/List';

    const DataArr = () => {
        const fruits = ["banana", "apple", "pear", "melon", "lemon"];
        return (
            <div className="DataArr">
                <List fruits={fruits} />
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default DataArr;
```

**LIST.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from './Item';

const List = (props) =>
        {props.fruits.map(fruit, index) => 
              <Item key={index} fruit={fruit} />};
export default List;
```

**ITEM.JS**

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = (props) => {props.fruit};

export default Item;
```